# Using jq with Jenkins pipeline

Tags: json, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jq, jenkins-groovy

In my use case i'm running a pipeline which calls aws cli via the withAWS plugin. I use jq to get the needed data, Now the sh returns the output as String. How do i convert this output to json object ?

```
withAWS(credentials: aws_env_credential){
    efs_details = sh(
    script: "aws efs describe-file-systems --region='${aws_region_for_cluster}' | jq --arg efs_name ${efs_name} '.[] | .[] | select(.Name==$efs_name)'",
    encoding: 'UTF-8',
    returnStdout: true
    )
```

Output:
efs_details:

```
{
 "OwnerId: "2142342325",
 "name": "my_volume",
 "encrypted": true,
 ...
}
```

here `efs_details` is a `java.lang.String` type.

Q: How do i convert this output to json so that i can use the dot operator. (example `efs_details.name`)

Comment: The aws command has an option: `--output json`. If that doesn't help, perhaps it would be worthwhile trying the -R option of jq.

Comment: trying the -r didn't really help as the output returned is of the type `string` ; so no changes using the `--raw-output`

Comment: The -R option is not the same as -r.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by writing a helper function that uses the JsonSurplerClassic() to convert the string to json.

```
def make_json(string_val){
   def jsonmaker = new JsonSlurperClassic()
   def jsonval = jsonmaker.parseText(string_val)
   println jsonval.getClass()
   return jsonval
}
```

**Notes:**

- This helper is using `JsonSlurperClassic()` as it creates a hashmap
      and avoids the jenkins `NotSerializableException` exception if we
      use the `JsonSurpler()`
- Secondly calling this helper solved the jenkins exception error rather than writing it inside the `withAWS...` block.

Following worked :

```
withAWS(credentials: aws_env_credential){
    efs_details = sh(
    script: "aws efs describe-file-systems --region='${aws_region_for_cluster}' | jq --arg efs_name ${efs_name} '.[] | .[] | select(.Name==$efs_name)'",
    encoding: 'UTF-8',
    returnStdout: true
    )
    efs_details_json = make_json(efs_details)
    }
```

Can now use the dot operators,

```
efs_details_json.name
efs_details_json.OwnerId
...
```

Hope this helps other(me in future) to save time for more non-trivial items.

Comment: `jq` can accept a json string directly.  like . `echo '{x:1, y:2}' | jq '.x'`. I think no need to convert to a JSON object.